# time diffrence in double digit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

i want to display TravelTimeHoursDiff and TravelTimeMinutesDiff in double digit now my time is shown as 7:0 i want to display like 07:00

```
 if ($scope.DispatchStatus.ArrivalTime != undefined){
                var today = $rootScope.getSysDate().split(" ");
                var timeArrival = new Date(today[0] + ' ' + $scope.DispatchStatus.ArrivalTime);
                var TravelTime = new Date(today[0] + ' ' + $scope.Route.TravelTime);
                var timeArrivalHours = timeArrival.getHours();
                var TravelTimeHoursDiff = timeArrivalHours - TravelTime.getHours() ;
                var TravelTimeMinutesDiff = (timeArrival.getMinutes() - TravelTime.getMinutes());

                    if(TravelTimeHoursDiff < 0 || (TravelTimeHoursDiff <= 0 && TravelTimeMinutesDiff < 0) || (TravelTimeHoursDiff == 0 && TravelTimeMinutesDiff == 0)){                    
                        $scope.formvalidationbit = $scope.DispatchStatusAddForm[fieldName].$invalid = true;
                         angular.element('#' + fieldName).addClass('ng-invalid');
                         angular.element('#' + fieldName).removeClass('ng-valid');
                         $scope.DispatchStatusAddForm.$valid = false;
                         var errorbit = 1;

                    }else{
                        if (isNaN(TravelTimeHoursDiff)) {
                             TravelTimeHoursDiff = '--';
                         }
                         if (isNaN(TravelTimeMinutesDiff)) {
                             TravelTimeMinutesDiff = '--';
                         }
                         if(TravelTimeMinutesDiff <0){
                             TravelTimeMinutesDiff = TravelTimeMinutesDiff * (-1);
                         }
                         $scope.TravelTime = TravelTimeHoursDiff + ':' + TravelTimeMinutesDiff;
                    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add leading `0` to values smaller then `10`, something like:

```
let addLeadingZero(v){
    return v < 10 ? ("0" + v) : v;
}
$scope.TravelTime = addLeadingZero(TravelTimeHoursDiff) + ':' + addLeadingZero(TravelTimeMinutesDiff);
```